# Change JFrame's background in Sea-Glass Look and Feel

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, nimbus

What's is the proper way to change to background of JFrame with Sea-Glass Look and Feel, so far I tried both :

```
frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.blue);
```

and

```
JPanel x = new JPanel();
x.setBackground(Color.red);
frame.setContentPane(x);
```

But it didn't make any effect :

```
import javax.swing.*;
import com.seaglasslookandfeel.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Color.*; 
public class BORDER_TEST {
public static void main(String[] a){

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {

                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.seaglasslookandfeel.SeaGlassLookAndFeel");
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                    JPanel x = new JPanel();
                    x.setBackground(Color.red);
                    frame.setContentPane(x);

                    //frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.blue);
                    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(900,350));
                    frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

}

Comment: Load L&F via UIManager before any code in your main method instead. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541045/how-to-set-jframe-look-and-feel After that, do whatever you want i.e. change its background

Comment: Some L&Fs may need you to change a few UI properties by calling setProperty() or something. You may need to look into its doc. There is also L&Fs with a "buggy" implementation that doesn't allow you to change to something that you want! If this happens, you may need to override its paintComponent() to consume its default UI component paint behavior and apply a new component paint behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Seaglass](http://code.google.com/p/seaglass/) `Look and Feel` is based on `Nimbus`, then you have to accepting its built-in themes or set [Colors for Nimbus programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246589/how-to-change-the-background-color-for-jpanels-with-nimbus-look-and-feel/8247527#8247527)