# Look and feel setup for different OS

Tags: java, swing, window, look-and-feel

I want to run my application in different platform and i want to use different look and feel for each platform. could you please guide how can approach this?

This is what i did.
in main java class i added static block and by adding below condition.

```
if(System.getProperty("os.name").startsWith("Windows")) //Added for linux
{
  UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
}
else
{
  UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
}
```

When I run my application in linux platform, it is not showing metal look and feel rather it's showing java default look and feel mainly in `JOptionPane`.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps your answer is available here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html

Or read into this SO question:
[How to set jframe look and feel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541045/how-to-set-jframe-look-and-feel)

Comment: yes now I getting what i expected. but the JOptionPane shows without title bar.
could you please help me?

Comment: That may be an unrelated problem. Please post some code. It would be better to open another question for this second problem. Post a link to the new question as a comment here and I will try to help.

Comment: Also, feel free to accept my solution above if it helped (even though it wasn't a direct solution, and was actually more of a guide to the right solution). Your choice.

Answer (score 2):

Use the System Look And Feel.

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```